# AddIfNotNull Dictionary<string, dynamic> method

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I have multiple methods that create a strongly typed object. When I am mapping properties to this object I manually add the Key value pair to the dictionary, however some properties in the JSON that is being processed might not contain a value and next call it might contain a value.

How do I deal with keys that contain null to be not added to the list? Please note that I will have many other object types. Below is just one example

```
public TextType GetTextType(JToken token)
        {
            TextType text = new TextType()
            {
                type = "text",
                //Dictionary<string, dynamic>
                attributes = {
                    ["font-family"] = component.style.fontFamily, //NULL
                    ["font-size"] = component.style.fontSize, //12
                    ["font-style"] = component.style.fontStyle //Bold
                }
            };
            return text;
        }
```

Object:

```
public class TextItem
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, dynamic> attributes { get; set; }

    public TextItem()
    {
        attributes = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    }
}
```

I have this method and it throws "The name `attributes` does not exist in the current context"

```
public void AddAttribute( string key, dynamic value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        attributes[key] = value;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this method so that I can call it in multiple methods and only add key if it contains a value. As I do not want to write multiple if statements for all key value pairs.

Comment: Maybe you want to create extension method? `AddIfNotNull`

Comment: The questions title doesnt even match the problem you describe. You are talking about a compiler error but ask for advice on null handling.

Comment: @Johnny Do you have an example of this. Just unsure how I can reference everything together from my implementation

Comment: @CSharpie Sorry sharpie I have updated the title.

Comment: @Mask-dCodex I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe adding extension method to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, e.g.

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static void AddIfNotNull<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value)
        where TValue : class 
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
    }
}

textItem.attributes.AddIfNotNull(1, null); //won't be added
textItem.attributes.AddIfNotNull(1, "a"); //will be added
```

Comment: Thanks this should work I was too busy trying to implement it into the same class

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing works for checking null, but I can help with the error. If the name `attribute` doesn't exist, it's because you haven't passed in or have in scope a `TextItem` to get an attributes list from.

Here's an alternative fixed method:

```
public void AddAttribute( string key, dynamic value,  ref TextItem txtItem)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        txtItem.attributes[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Apologies that this isn't a comment, not got 50 rep.

Comment: Thank you larry, I understand that however I have multiple Item types, this would mean it will only handle TextItem but I have 5+ more objects to check key pairs unsure what to pass to this method to allow different object types.

Comment: Why `ref TextItem txtItem`?